# Web page layout with bootstrap-4.1.2

Tags: header, bootstrap-4, footer, program-entry-point

My goal is to get [image: the page] like this.

I use bootstrap-grid.min.css from bootstrap-4.1.2

What do I do wrong? [My code](https://codepen.io/iasynetska/pen/XBNWXY)

```
    <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh;">
            <section class="main d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-stretch">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="menu">
                        Aside
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <div class="text">
                         Main
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
        Footer
    </footer>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your structure. I have made some changes for you, please see if it serves the purpose.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="footer">
  Header
</header>
<div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 24px);">
  <section class="main d-flex flex-grow-1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="col col-md-3" style="background-color:blue;">
          <div class="menu">
            Aside
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-9" style="background-color:pink;">
          <div class="text">
            Main
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```